# Can you use Throne Room to Mine a Copper to a Gold?

Tags: dominion

One of the most frequent barely-civil discussions in my group is what is possible when you use Throne Room (repeat an action card), in conjunction with Mine (trash a treasure to gain a treasure with cost of three greater).

In my experience, one of two things happen:

1. The person trashes two copper to gain two silver - completely valid
2. The person trashes one copper to gain a gold - under debate

**Is it legal to gain a gold from a copper with a Throne Room-ed Mine?**

Comment: You can go from Copper to Silver (or Loan, or some other $3 treasure), and then from this newly gained Silver/Loan etc. (or any other treasure in your hand that costs $3+) to go to a Gold.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Yes**, you can trash Copper -> Silver -> Gold, since Mine requires you trash cards from your hand, and then gain them *back into your hand*, setting you up for another play.

Copper -> Platinum with a King's Courted Mine is also possible (and incredibly devious!)

For clarity, Mine reads:

> Trash a Treasure card from your hand. Gain a Treasure card costing up to 3 Coins more; put it into your hand.

And Throne Room reads:

> Choose an Action card in your hand. Play it twice.

So the order is (with a hand like Throne Room, Mine, Copper, X, X):

1. Play Throne Room
2. Choose Mine
3. Trash Copper from hand; Gain Silver into your hand
4. Use Mine again
5. Trash Silver from hand; Gain Gold into hand
6. Profit

Comment: As I was writing the question out, and remembered the wording of cards (specifically *put it **into your hand***, and *Treasure card **from your hand***), I came to the same conclusion. Love the idea about King's Court though, that'll be epic when we play next.

Comment: Just a caveat: the trashing does require gaining a Silver (or other 3-cost treasure) first. If you can't gain a Silver or similar for any reason (e.g. there are none left), you cannot go from Copper to Gold.

Comment: Is there any other forseeable reason why I wouldn't be able to gain a silver, besides them all being gone? I don't have most of the expansions so I don't know what all the cards do.

Comment: @pandorym I actually can't think of any off the top of my head. The pile emptying is definitely the most likely scenario but there could be an Embargo-like situation, where you COULD gain one, but don't want to for whatever reason and you wouldn't be allowed to shortcut to the Gold (and Embargo wouldn't apply in this situation anyway since it only affects buys)

Comment: @pandorym A more simple example of when you might be able to take a Silver but not want to: when doing so would end the game while you're behind.

Comment: It's also important that the Silver is gained and trashed for several Dark Ages cards like Forager, Graverobber, and Rogue.

Comment: @sitnaltax - The Hinterlands cards Trader and Jack of All Trades also tend to deplete the Silver pile.